# Memcached server service suddenly stops working

Tags: memcached, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a Memcached server service installed on Windows Server 2012 R2. Default settings are used. Sometimes the service stops working without any errors. Firewall and antivirus are disabled.

I wrote an utility that collects Memcached statistics every 30 mins, and the statistics looks fine: `evictions` and `listen_disabled_num` are always 0, `curr_connections` is around 30, `accepting_conns` is 1.

What can cause the Memcached service to stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in exceeding maximum item size. We used version 1.2.6 and this version din't want to work with objects greater than 1024 kB. After moving to version 1.4.5 the problem has gone. The newer version introduces -I command-line parameter, which allows to adjust maximum item size up to 128MB.